# Cant see any page on magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I am facing the following problem

http://www.theprinterdepot.net/hp-5000dn-printer-refurbished.html

all product pages are blank, but if you go to the homepage, or a category page or a search results page its working.

ini errors in enabled so I have no idea where to look for the error.

Comment: The default path is magento/var/log/. The two files to look for are system.log and exception.log

Comment: Go to System -> Configuration -> Developer. Then look for Log Settings section, and make sure that it is enabled and check the name of your log files there.

Comment: can you please check the error_reporting settings through phpinfo() from your Magento installation dir?

Comment: @Dick Laurent, can you please explain? did you mean index.php? error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);?4

Comment: @arunkumar, indeed it was disabled, I enabled it, and then I refreshed the page, the files are not yet generated there, there is no exception.log or system.log.  Please help! :(

Comment: for logs please check if your var dir has writing permissions

Comment: for error reporting please set error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)

Comment: As far as I see you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this my self after clearing all magento cache. I also had to put the old theme I was using, the creators of the theme told me that it only allows magento 1.4.1.1 to 1.5.1.1 and my installation was 1.4.0.1.

I think that was the problemm